# Como obter o maior e o menor número entre 15 números digitados? C++

Tags: c++, loop, contador

Algorítmo que leia 15 números reais, e escreva o maior e o menor entre os números lidos. Não estou conseguindo fazer a parte de escrever o menor e maior dos números digitados.

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float numero;
    int cont;
    cont=1;
    while(cont<=15) {
       cout << ("Digite um numero real:");
       cin >> numero;
       cont++;
    }
}
```

Como obter o maior e o menor número entre os números digitados?

Comment: Defina as variáveis `maior` e `menor`, após a leitura de num faça: `if (cont == 1) menor = maior = num; else {if (num > maior) maior = num; if (num < menor) menor = num;}`. Após o loop imprima as variáveis `maior` e `menor`.

Comment: @anonimo não seria melhor utilizar o `std::set` ou um `vector` com o `algorithm`?

Comment: Estava seguindo a linha que diogoBRRN estava seguindo no desenvolvimento e ele não estava utilizando tais features e existe solução possível sem utiliza-las..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira que eu considero muito boa é utilizar [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) e o [`algorithm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/), eles já possuem uma função para ver o menor valor e o maior, assim não será necessario utilizar nenhum `if`.

Código:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm> 

using namespace std;
int main(){
    float numero;
    vector<float> num;
    int cont, maximo, minimo;
    cont=1;
    while(cont<=15) {
       cout << ("Digite um numero real:");
       cin >> numero;
       num.push_back(numero);
       cont++;
    }

    cout << "Maior valor digitado: " << *max_element(num.begin(), num.end()) << endl;
    cout << "Menor valor digitado: " << *min_element(num.begin(), num.end()) << endl;

}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@Cdigodede/MotionlessExoticDehardwarization#main.cpp)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode insirir os dados de entrada em um `std::set`, que é um container ordenado, e então basta pegar o primeiro elemento (menor) e o último elemento (maior).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main( [[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char ** argv )
{
  // a inicialização é para simular a entrada de dados
  std::set<float> numbers = { 100.1, 23.3, 84.3, -1.4, 1234.5, /* ... */ 40.22 };

  std::cout << "Min:" << *numbers.begin() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Max:" << *numbers.rbegin() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maneira curta e simples, vou seguir essa resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

Defina duas variáveis de controle do tipo *float*, sendo elas `maior` e `menor`. Após a leitura do atributo `numero` faça a seguinte validação:

```
//Verifica se é o primeiro número digitado e define o valor das variáveis maior e menor igual ao número.
if (cont == 1) {
    maior = numero;
    menor = maior;
}
else if (numero > maior) //Verifica se o número digitado é maior do que o maior dos números digitados.
    maior = numero;
else if (numero < menor) //Verifica se o número digitado é menor do que o menor dos números digitados.
    menor = numero;
```

Código modificado:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float numero, maior, menor;
    int cont = 1;
    while (cont <= 15) {
       cout << ("Digite um numero real:");
       cin >> numero;
       if (cont == 1) {
           maior = numero;
           menor = maior;
       }
       else if (numero > maior) {
           maior = numero;
       }
       else if (numero < menor) {
           menor = numero;
       }
       cont++;
    }
    cout << "Menor numero: " << menor << "\nMaior numero: " << maior << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leia um número, considere esse número como sendo tanto o maior como o menor até o momento.

Leia os outros 14 e vá comparando com o maior e o menor até o momento atual.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   float numero, maior, menor;
   int cont;
   cont=1;
   cout << ("Digite um numero real:");
   cin >> numero;
   maior = menor = numero
   while(cont< 15) {
       // aqui você coloca o código pra atualizar as variáveis maior e menor
       cont++;
}
```

}

Comment: Mas é justamente essa comparação que ele não sabe